# Metrics on time to make decisions in live play?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, etiquette

Are there any metrics out there that determine the average length of time you have to make a decision in live poker?

For example, let's take a tournament scenario, the antes and the blinds are out there and you are in middle position - how many seconds (minutes??) do you have before you have to make a decision? How much time do you have in late position/button?

Does anyone know if metrics like this exist? I'm assuming the answer is just a few seconds - maybe less than 10 secs for most positions but I want to know if anyone has studied this or if there are sources I can cite.

Comment: The WSOP no-limit official rule is one minute *after* someone has requested the clock on a player. (http://www.wsop.com/poker-rules/rules_nlpl.asp) It seems likely that other cardrooms could have their own policies.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer thank you. I understand that those are *maximum* times but I'm looking for the *average* time. In other words, between the time your hole cards reach you and when the action is on you.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  It would be interesting to see that info and how that number changes throughout the course of a major tournament. My guess is that it might be hard to come by. I'm sure online poker providers could easily produce those stats in an online scenario, but in a live setting it seems unlikely that data are available except in cases like the WSOP main event final table where it was televised in its entirety. Good luck.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Indeed, I think it will be very hard to find this info. I'm guessing that it's measured in seconds - but I would love to find a source that I can actually cite. I agree with you though, I doubt many people have studied this formally

Comment: I played with gruop of friends and sone of them take long time to think.after long tine then I have have to give them 1 minute again.seens too long..how long you think it should be?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is unanswerable. If you have n players before you, and the maximum time they have to decide is t seconds, then you have at most n*t seconds. But we all know that most players won't take that long to decide. I would guess that the distributions of time taken is uniform, meaning that the average time you get to decide is n*t/2. If the distribution is different (but this depends on so many variables) and the average time was v, then you get n*v (seconds) to decide.

I doubt there are any metrics available - you could produce your own if you want to.